# How to get multiple API fetch data avoid first consle.log empty array

Tags: javascript, react-native, fetch-api, map-function

When i am trying to fetch multiple API using map() method, and launch the project it's given me empty which is i understand my console.log couldn't able to fetch at the time, and just use **Ctrl+s** press to save the file again, it's start to giving me value in react native vs code. in this case how can i avoid to launch the project and again **Ctrl+s** press.
**what should i use to avoid them and once i launch, i will able to fetch the data.**

i already have tried setinterval but it's repeating me empty array, the setinterval isn't reach to fetch again.

should i try any function for it or something?

here is my code in vs code:

```
const [dataLoc, setDataLoc] = useState([]);
const ids = [1,2,3,4,5];

useEffect(() => {
  ids?.map((id) => {
    fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${id}`)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((dataLoc) => setDataLoc((prev) => [...prev, dataLoc.title]))
      .catch((error) => console.error(error));
  });
}, []);

console.log(dataLoc);
```

when i tried it to run in vs code i get this problem as i mention already.

Anyone can help me? i'm stack at the place for a long time. i appreciate your trying.
Thanks for your trying in advance!

Comment: It'd be nice if you paste the code so it's easier to understand what you're trying to do

Comment: i already add my code here

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about

Comment: it's giving me empty array for the first console.log(), i can't able to view my data when i launch the project.

Comment: try this code in VS Code framework to check please

Comment: Your question is hard to understand... What exactly are you asking: Why your state is an empty array on the first render? Why the fetch and state setting is not working as expected? Please clarify.

Comment: Ok, first you need to modify your fetching approach... The promises won't be awaited if you fetch the data using `map` like that. You should be using `Promise.all`, `Promise.allSettled` or even a `for...of` loop if you want the calls to be made sequentially.

Comment: @PeterTam i tried as you said but still it's same

Comment: @ivanatias as simple as it is that when i tried to fetch data, it's giving me empty array, inside array should be data from api. you can tried this code in vs code, online emulator is works so please try in vs code.

Comment: You are putting your `console.log()` directly in your default export function. That means when you set any state in this functional component. It will re-render once and `log()` will be called.

Comment: @ivanatias if you can help me kindly to modify my code, because i used before Promise.all  but i couldn,t make it.

Comment: Try `Promise.all` to make requests in a loop (in your case inside a map). There are some examples online

Comment: useEffect(() => {
        Promise.all(devices?.map(async (id) => {
            return new Promise((resolve) => {
 fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${id}`)
                    .then((response) => response.json())
                  .then((dataLoc) => setDataLoc((prev) => [...prev, dataLoc.title]))
                    .catch((error) => console.error(error))
            })
        }))
    }, []);                                           i tried Promise all it's giving me ( " ERROR  TypeError: Array.from requires an array-like object - not null or undefined" )  this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid Warn: Possible unhandled Promise Rejection (id:0)

```
   useEffect(() => {
     fetchData();
    }, []);
    
    async function fetchData(){
    
    try{
const requestArray = await Promise.all(ids?.map((id) => {
        return fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${id}`)
          .then((response) => response.json())
          .then((dataLoc) => {
            return dataLoc.title;
          })
          .catch((error) => console.error(error));
      }));
    
      console.log(JSON.stringify(requestArray));
      setDataLoc(requestArray);
    }
    catch (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try the `Promise.all()` approach mentioned in comments above.

```
useEffect(() => {
 fetchData();
}, []);

async function fetchData(){
  const requestArray = await Promise.all(ids?.map((id) => {
    return fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${id}`)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((dataLoc) => {
        return dataLoc.title;
      })
      .catch((error) => console.error(error));
  }));

  console.log(JSON.stringify(requestArray));
  setDataLoc(requestArray);
}
```

Comment: btw i am having this WARN  Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0): ,,,,How can i avoid it, any idea?

Comment: Would you please put the full warning here?

Comment: i alreadt solve the issues using try and catch, Thanks for your helping!!!!